# How to prevent a component with position relative do not appear above the table with sticky header in angular?

Tags: css, angular

I've an html table with sticky header.

```
position: sticky
```

I also have a checkbox component made with its :host position relative.

```
position: relative
```

This checkbox component is inside the body row.

ie the first cell will have a checkbox

```
 <td>
<custom-checkbox></custom-checkbox>
<td>
```

But the issue is that since this checkbox is made with position relative ( for :host of checkbox component) it is appearing above the sticky header when scrolled down (EVERYTHING ELSE IN THE ROWS FROM THE BODY IS BEHAVING NORMALLY - I.E. TEXT). I tried applying z-index for this custom-checkbox component & also for the sticky header, but nothing is working out. But when I remove the position relative from the :host of checkbox-component it is not appearing above the sticky header. But then the checkbox component stops working.

Suggest some solutions.

Comment: can you provide HTML of those elements?

Comment: add a z-index to the sticky element ;) you should provide enough code here in a snippet ( button [<>] or a fiddle/codepen demonstrating your issue. |-|  check it here https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/gOPpxjP

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62272309/how-to-prevent-a-child-component-with-position-relative-do-not-appear-above-the